# Server Error in '/' Application resource cannot be found error only for aspx page in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

When i try to access .aspx page and try to navigate from cshtml to aspx page. It throws me

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

I didnt use any code. I just created .aspx format in view instead of razor engine i used aspx engine.

I set the starting page URL in properties->web->specificpage.

It throws me the above mentioned error.

I couldnt find the reason behind this issue. When i try to access the cshtml page it works fine.

Please help me to overcome the issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide more detail on your problem ?

Comment: Hi Athiban, I Like to set .aspx page as my start page . I don't want cshtml page to run .

Comment: do you have cshtml file and aspx file in same name ?

Comment: No Athiban. I gave different names only

Comment: If you need to set the default startpage you just need to set the action name and controller name in the `RouteConfig`,
`routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "yourContollerName", action = "YourActionName", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set the default startpage you just need to set the action name and controller name in the `RouteConfig`,

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    name: "Default", 
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { 
          controller = "yourContollerName", 
          action = "YourActionName", 
          id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```